# Corrupt ZIP file if calling Save twice

Tags: c#, stream, zip, dotnetzip

I am using [`DotNetZip`](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd) 1.9.6 in my application which uses a file structure similar to e.g. *.docx: Zip file containing XML files.
Now every module of the application can store such XML files to my custom file management and on "save" they are serialized to streams which are then saved to the Zip file via DotNetZip.
To update the entries I use `ZipFile.UpdateEntry(path, stream)`.
This works fine and the first time I save my file via calling `ZipFile.Save()` everything works.

But If I do this a second time (first some `UpdateEntry`calls then `Save`) on the same instance the Zip file is corrupted: The file structure and meta-data (e.g. uncompressed size of each file) is still there, but all files are 0 byte in compressed size.

If I create a new instance from the just saved file after saving everything works fine, but shouldn't it be possible to avoid that and "reuse" the same instance?

The following example (also see https://dotnetfiddle.net/mHxEIy) can be used to reproduce the problem:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var zipFile = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile();

        var content1 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Content 1"));
        zipFile.UpdateEntry("test.txt", content1);

        zipFile.Save("test.zip"); // here the Zip file is correct
        //zipFile = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile("test.zip"); // uncomment and it works too

        var content2 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Content 2"));
        zipFile.UpdateEntry("test.txt", content2);

        zipFile.Save();  // after that it is corrupt
    }
}
```

To run this you need to add the "DotNetZip 1.9.6" NuGet package.

After the first save, this is what you get:
[image: Correct]
and after the second save:
[image: Corrupt]

Comment: Much better, thanks - and yes, let's delete comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suspected this was a bug in `DotNetZip` up to version `1.9.6`.
I think I was able to fix this with [THIS](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd/pull/54) change which was just released as version `1.9.7` on NuGet. At least for me the problem does not happen anymore.

*Some background what happend as far as I found out:*
When you call `Save` the library sets an internal flag which remembers that the ZIP file was just save and on the second `Save` call instead of "recompressing" all entries in the ZIP file it copies them from the just saved file.
This works fine for adding/removing entries, but breaks when one of the entries was changed as then it "mixes" the old and the new entry and produces the inconsisten ZIP file.
My fix basically disables that "copy from old file" logic if an entry was changed.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it's a bug in the library, around removing an entry. If you *just* remove an entry and then save again, it correctly removes the file.

However, if you remove an entry and then add another one with the same name - which is what `UpdateEntry` is documented to do if the entry already exists - the old entry appears to be used instead.

The reason you're ending up with an empty file the second time is that the original `MemoryStream` is being read again - but by now, it's positioned at the end of the data, so there's no data to read. If you reset the position to the start of the stream (`content1.Position = 0;`) it will rewrite the original data. If you *modify* the data within `content1`, you end up with invalid compressed data.

The only workaround I can immediately think of is to keep your own map from filename to `MemoryStream`, and replace the contents of each `MemoryStream` when you want to update it... or just load the file each time, as per your existing workaround.

It's definitely worth filing a bug around this though, as it *should* work as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks fo your answer and your time looking into this - I will file a bug in GitHub for `DotNetZip` and report back here if something comes out of it...

Comment: As just posted as the new answer: I think I was able to fix the bug and a new version of `DotNetZip` was just released. Thanks again for your help - it helped me find the right place.